# How do I change the color of stacked bar in R?

Tags: r

Could you please help me with it? I would like to change the clear for white, rain for blue, sleet for light blue, snow for light gray, fog for light orange and windy for light yellow. I have created a stacked bar in the following.

[image]

```
barplot(tabl2, xlab="Injury level", xaxt = "n",
        legend=c("Clear", "Rain", "Sleet", "Snow", "Fog", "Windy"), col=1:6)
axis(1, at=seq(from=0.75, to=3.15, by=1.2), labels = c("Minor", "Serious", "Fatal"))
```

Answer (score 1):

See here that

```
d.Titanic <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

> levels(d.Titanic$Class)
[1] "1st"  "2nd"  "3rd"  "Crew"
```

colors correspond to above levels. If you need other colors, see `colors()` for all "word" colors. Or use a hex notation. The choices don't end there.

```
barplot(Freq ~ Class + Survived, data = d.Titanic,
        subset = Age == "Adult" & Sex == "Male",
        main = "barplot(Freq ~ Class + Survived, *)", 
        col = c("red", "green", "blue", "white"),
        ylab = "# {passengers}", legend = TRUE)
```

[image]